# Exception while running Robolectric for vector drawable

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to run Robolectric test. I'm getting the following error once I run the test

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052

```
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:87)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.__constructor__(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
at com.intelibems.activity.MyNotificationListActivity.onCreate(MyNotificationListActivity.java:58)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:232)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:73)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:366)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$1.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:27)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:70)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:80)
at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:172)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:102)
at com.intelibems.activity.MyNotificationListActivityTest.checkViewExists(MyNotificationListActivityTest.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:497)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:228)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:110)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:64)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I'm running Robolectric 3.4.2 in Android studio 2.3.3. for Windows 7

Comment: Do you see a message in the log that AndroidManifest not found? If you run it from the command line do you see same error?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes, I'm seeing message in the log that AndroidManifest not found. Let me try running through command line. I haven't run command before.

Comment: Did it succeed?

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Nop. :(